# Figuring out logic behind def McNuggets(n) solved using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I understand how recursion works, but there's a step in this problem that has had be confused for hours.

```
   def McNuggets(n):
        """
        n is an int

        Returns True if some integer combination of 6, 9 and 20 equals n
        Otherwise returns False.
        """
        # Your Code Here   
        if n == 0:
            return True
        for i in (6, 9, 20):
            if n >= i and McNuggets(n - i):
                return True
        return False
    McNuggets(15)





___________________________________________________________________________
Frames                     Objects
Global frame
McNuggets [------------------> McNuggets(n)

McNuggets
    n|15
    i|6

McNuggets
    n|9
    i|9
```

I don't get how the value of i goes from being 6 to being 9 after returning false and going back through the recursion steps.  I tried to post a pic, but I wasn't able.  I wanted to recreate the 23 step from typing the code into http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Step 23, the reason `i` is `9` is because McNuggets(15-9) was still being resolved, `McNuggets(9)`'s for loop was finishing execution. Up to that point the `i=6` when the condition `McNuggets(9-6)` resolved, so `i=9` was next. As a result `McNuggets(9-9)` was next.